# Consistent estimator of function of moments up to given order

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, estimation, moment-generating-functions

Asume we the moments of a distribution exist up to order $n$. Consider the estimator $$t (x)=f(m_1(x),..., m_n(x)) $$
where $m_k(x):=1/r \sum_{i=1}^r  x^k$.
We assume we have $r$ samples of the distribution and that $f$ is continuous function mapping to $\mathbb{R}$.

I want to show that this estimator $t(x)$ is consistent for $f(e_1,...,e_n)$, where $e_k := E[X^k]$

I thought about using the definition. But there is an alternative. If the estimator is unbiased und has finite variance, then it is consistent.

But how can I see that? I know nothing about the function $f$. Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach will not work as you aren't even guaranteed that $f$ admits a finite variance. Instead, consider the following.

By the law of large numbers, each of your sample moments is consistent, i.e.
$$\frac{1}{r}\sum_{j=1}^r x_r^k \to E(X^k)$$
in probability as $r \to \infty$. Thus, by the [continuous mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_mapping_theorem) we conclude that
$$f(m_1, \ldots , m_n) \to f(e_1, \ldots , e_n)$$
in probability as $r \to \infty$.

Comment: Is this the convergence that  prob of the difference greater than some constant Epsilon is 0?

Comment: @Alif $X_n \to X$ in probability is defined as: $\forall > 0 $, $\lim_{n \to \infty} P(|X_n - X| > \epsilon) =0$. An estimator is consistent for a parameter $\theta$ when it converges in probability to $\theta$.

Comment: Thank York very much.